# Forma correcta de ordenar registros

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas espero que me puedan ayudar, tengo dos tablas con los siguientes datos:

(Tabla Cliente)

```
clienteid  nombre   direccion  telefono  email   
---------  -------  ---------  --------  --------
001        gallo                                 
002        salcedo                               
003        paul                                  
41422102   sistema
```

(Tabla Movimiento)

```
movimientoid  fecha       cuentaid  clienteid  monto       tipo  descripcion        
------------  ----------  --------  ---------  --------  ------  -------------------
           1  2018-11-01  CAJA-001  41422102   10000.00       1  Saldo Inicial      
           2  2018-11-01  CAJA-001  003        5000.00       -1  Compra Al Contado  
           3  2018-11-01  CAJA-001  003        100.00        -1  Compra Al Contado  
           4  2018-11-01  CAJA-001  41422102   100.00        -1  Compra Al Contado
```

Realizo una consulta con la tabla movimientos y me devuelve los resultados ordenados:

```
SET @dispo=0;
SELECT movimientoId, DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%y') fecha, descripcion, 
IF(tipo=1, monto, NULL) deposito, IF(tipo=-1, monto, NULL) retiro,
IF(tipo=1,@dispo:=@dispo + monto,@dispo:=@dispo - monto) disponible FROM movimiento
 WHERE movimiento.cuentaid='CAJA-001' AND movimiento.fecha BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-01';

movimientoId  fecha     descripcion        deposito  retiro   disponible  
------------  --------  -----------------  --------  -------  ------------
           1  01/11/18  Saldo Inicial      10000.00  (NULL)   10000.00    
           2  01/11/18  Compra Al Contado  (NULL)    5000.00  5000.00     
           3  01/11/18  Compra Al Contado  (NULL)    100.00   4900.00     
           4  01/11/18  Compra Al Contado  (NULL)    100.00   4800.00
```

Ahora quiero incluir el nombre del cliente, pero es aquí donde la consulta me devuelve registros desordenados:

```
SET @dispo=0;
SELECT movimientoId, DATE_FORMAT(fecha, '%d/%m/%y') fecha, descripcion, nombre,
IF(tipo=1, monto, NULL) deposito, IF(tipo=-1, monto, NULL) retiro,
IF(tipo=1,@dispo:=@dispo + monto,@dispo:=@dispo - monto) disponible 
FROM movimiento INNER JOIN cliente ON movimiento.clienteid=cliente.clienteid
  WHERE movimiento.cuentaid='CAJA-001' AND movimiento.fecha BETWEEN '2018-11-01' AND '2018-11-01';

movimientoId  fecha     descripcion        nombre   deposito  retiro   disponible  
------------  --------  -----------------  -------  --------  -------  ------------
           2  01/11/18  Compra Al Contado  paul     (NULL)    5000.00  -5000.00    
           3  01/11/18  Compra Al Contado  paul     (NULL)    100.00   -5100.00    
           1  01/11/18  Saldo Inicial      sistema  10000.00  (NULL)   4900.00     
           4  01/11/18  Compra Al Contado  sistema  (NULL)    100.00   4800.00
```

**Desordenado** por la columna `MovimientoId` o al menos eso pensé, ya que pude darme cuenta que los registros se ordenaban según la `PK` de la tabla cliente `clienteId`. Ya me explicaron que la ordenación de los registros por default depende del motor, lo hice con `ORDER BY movimientoId` y si sale en orden pero los resultado de la columna `depósito`, `retiro` y `disponible` se calculan mal. De que forma puede ser mi consulta? Gracias.

Comment: El order, es lo ultimo que se aplica en una consulta a DB. Para lo que vos estas tratando de hacer, que no deberia hacerse asi, si no que el saldo deberia estar ya calculado en otro lado, vas a tener que hacer un procedimiento que trabaje sobre los datos ordenados.

Comment: Yo creo que el problema no es el orden en sí, sino la cuestión de los cálculos que haces. Generalmente cuando se hace tan difícil obtener unos resultados tan fáciles, es porque subyace algún error en el diseño de la base de datos misma o en la forma de enfocar la consulta...

Comment: De que otra forma lo puedo hacer teniendo esas tablas?